# Use restricted-shell-escape with TexStudio on TexLive?

Tags: texlive, shell-escape

The package auto-pst-pdf.sty needs shell-escape to run, but shell escape is known to be seriously unsafe. Is there a possibility to tell auto-pst-pdf.sty to use restricted-shell-escape instead? I'm working on Linux Mint KDE 15 and I'm relatively new both to Linux and TeX, so be prepared for stupid questions on you answers.

Comment: You have to add `latex` to the list of “safe” programs, which is obviously discouraged.

Comment: Hmm, what's the way to do so? But I'm not sure, if this is the problem. I think it's trying to use the normal shell-escape, which is for good reasons forbidden in TexLive. So I have to tell auto-pst-pdf to use restricted-shell-escape instead of the normal one. How do I do that?

Comment: Related: [Security in autogenerated latex scripts. How to avoid LaTeX Injection? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/552887/security-in-autogenerated-latex-scripts-how-to-avoid-latex-injection?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no real difference in how restricted and unrestricted shell-escape work as far as calling the operating system is concerned.

The unrestricted shell-escape is usually enabled, but it allows running only programs listed in a special variable set in `texmf.cnf`; currently the list is

```
shell_escape_commands = bibtex,bibtex8,kpsewhich,makeindex,mpost,repstopdf,
```

The restricted shell escape does *not* create a sandbox; the listed program are trusted not to be able to make uncontrolled reads and writes: they can only write in the current directory or below it, for instance. But in the end, the same system call as with the unrestricted shell-escape is performed.

You *could* add `latex` and `gs` to the list, which is necessary for `auto-pst-pdf` to work, but this would open the same security problems as running the program with `--shell-escape`.

The system calls generated by `auto-pst-pdf` are equivalent to running the file through

```
latex + dvips + ps2pdf
```

so they should be safe. If *other* code in your document triggers system calls, then `--shell-escape` could be dangerous. Documents obtained from trusted sources (in particular written by you) shouldn't be risky. No package relying on `--shell-escape` has, up to my knowledge, created problems. Of course there's always the possibility of receiving malicious code from untrusted sources.

Comment: So this means if I want to keep my Linux safe I cannot use auto-pst-pdf?

Comment: @Jörg Did I say that? No. If you want a fully safe computer, just don't use it. Be cautious, that's all. In particular, `auto-pst-pdf` doesn't do more than you would do by running `latex+dvips+ps2pdf`.

Comment: Ok, I interpreted your answer like that, that's why I asked again. But you are right: As long as I don't copy bad code in TexStudio and compile it, I should be save. Is that what you meant? Thanks for being patient with me :)