# An error while compiling

Tags: pdftex

I downloaded the template from [here](http://www.iaeng.org/WCE2017/doc/IAENG_Conference_LaTeX_BibTeX_template.zip) and compiled it, I get the error

```
NEURAL_NETWORK not found. \includegraphics[width=2.5in]{NEURAL_NETWORK}
```

Then, I compiled it in an other PC, there is no problem. What is the problem in my PC and how can I solve the problem?

Comment: What is the file type? What are you compiling with (LaTeX, pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX,...)?

Comment: The document compiles for me out of the box. The file is an `.eps` file. so using `pdflatex`, the automatic conversion to `.pdf` is necessary (or converting it beforehand. Is `--shell-escape` enabled? It may be called `--enable-write18` as well.

Comment: @werner, the default compiler is pdflatex. File type is an .eps file. How can I solve it (I am beginner forgive me)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am using Texstudio. How can adjust it? ( I guess it is disable)

Comment: @captain23: I don't use such 'editors', perhaps the answer in this link will help you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147468/use-restricted-shell-escape-with-texstudio-on-texlive